# Как указать путь до темы Gtk?

Tags: gtk

Чтобы изменить тему gtk приложения, при запуске достаточно указать ее название

```
 GTK_THEME=название_темы ./исполняемыйфайл 
 GTK_THEME=Adwaita ./test
```

При это путь до темы такой:

```
 /usr/share/themes/Adwaita
```

Однако данная команда не работает:

```
GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita ./test
```

Допустим я хочу установить тему по другому пути, как мне тогда запускать gtk приложение с этой темой?

Comment: вроде есть только два места: захардкоженый "~/.themes" и заданный в момент сборки gtk "${prefix}/share/themes" (собственно обычно это `/usr/...` ... ни каких других путей для поиска темы ЕМНИП нет, но чтобы сказать наверняка надо смотреть документацию (возможно и «исходную»)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете пойти по одному из путей:

Поместить тему по адресу

```
~/.theme/Theme-Name
```

тогда команда будет

```
GTK_THEME=Theme-Name ./test
```

Поместить тему по адресу

```
$GTK_DATA_PREFIX/share/themes/Theme-Name
```

тогда команда будет

```
GTK_DATA_PREFIX=/path/to/prefix GTK_THEME=Theme-Name ./test
```

либо загрузить CSS напрямую, вставив в один из файлов

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

строку, напоминающую что-то вроде

```
@import url("resource:///org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-main.css");
```

Или загрузить CSS вызывая функции напрямую

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_file() 

gtk_style_context_add_provider()
```

Также можно скомпилировать свой файл ресурсов используя, например вот такой скриптец:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=$1
SOURCE=$2
DEST=./build/$NAME

echo "Building theme $NAME"

rm -rf "$DEST"
cp -r "$SOURCE" "$DEST"

FILES=$(find "$DEST" -type f -printf "%P\n" | xargs -i echo "    <file>{}</file>")

cat <<EOF >"$DEST/gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/org/gnome/shell/theme">
$FILES
  </gresource>
</gresources>
EOF

(
  cd "$DEST"
  glib-compile-resources gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml
)
echo "-> $DEST/gnome-shell-theme.gresource"
```

Тогда можно использовать функцию

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_resource()
```

[Источник](https://superuser.com/questions/513377/how-to-override-gtk3-gnome-shell-themes-per-application)

[Документация](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html)

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ! Вы мне помогли!